# System time and file system time are not the same

Tags: linux, file, time, filesystems, kernel

I met a strange problem on one cluster with 10 nodes.

On any node, any file operation makes the access/modification/change time of that file in the future that is **1min52s after the current system time** obtained from `date`. That makes all `make` command cannot work correctly.

Following command are tested: `touch X`, `echo 123456 > X`, using `utimes(X,NULL)` and `utime(X,NULL)` with a C program. All of them can reproduce this problem.

Is there anyway to solve the problem? Thanks.

Comment: You mention cluster. Fix the clock on the machine that actually manages the disks.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, our NFS server was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to address this is to synchronize the clocks on all of the machines to a common time reference using [`ntp`](http://www.ntp.org/) (usually to a reliable time server).  [The NTP FAQ and HOWTO](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-a-faq.htm) is a good place to start.

For most Linux servers, just installing the `ntp` package takes you halfway.  You may need to [customize](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/basic-ntp-config.html) the configuration file (usually `/etc/ntp.conf`), as well as *enable* the service for `ntpd` (the NTP daemon).